# custom nested ordering in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

How can I order a datatable according to a nested, custom order?

```
library(data.table)

y <- data.table(a = c(1:2),
                b = c("Z", "Y", "X"),
                c = c(1:6))

desired_ordering_of_b <- c("Y", "Z", "X")

desired_dt <-
  data.table(
    a = as.integer(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)),
    b = c("Y", "Z", "X"),
    c = as.integer(c(5, 1, 3, 2, 4, 6))
  )
```

I can get the `b` column ordered itself, but not when I want to give a prioritized ordering of `a`before `b`.

```
y[desired_ordering_of_b,on="b"] ## gets me the ordering according to b

setorder(y[desired_ordering_of_b,on="b"],a,b) ##obviously looses it again
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
y[, b := factor(b, levels = c("Y", "Z", "X"), ordered = TRUE)]
setorder(y, a, b, c)

   a b c
1: 1 Y 5
2: 1 Z 1
3: 1 X 3
4: 2 Y 2
5: 2 Z 4
6: 2 X 6
```

Or even:

```
y[order(a, factor(b, levels = c("Y", "Z", "X"), ordered = TRUE), c)]
```

Comment: It is using `ordered = TRUE`. Or how do you mean it?

Comment: `y[, b := factor(b, levels = c("Y", "Z", "X"))] &  setorder(y,a,b)` gives the desired output as well--

Comment: Yes, it work as well. However, it could be safer to use the parameter `ordered = TRUE`.